# What is the equation of the line with the property that the shortest distance between that line and the parabola is 1?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conic-sections

What is the equation of the line with the property that the shortest distance between that line and the parabola is 1?

[image]

The parabola is $y=x^2$ and the linear pass (2,0). The shortest distance between that linear and the parabola is 1.

Normally, linear & parabola calculus problem will ask the equation of linear that touch the parabola at specific (x,y) point. I can solve that problem by finding the derivative of the parabola. Then put the x value into the derivative function to find the slope of the linear. After that, it isn't hard to find the equation of the linear.

But this question is different. It ask the equation of linear that have the shortest distance between that linear and the parabola is 1. I don't know how solve it. I know that the linear y=ax-2a since it pass (2,0) but don't know the next step.

I try plotting graph in Desmos. I think $a \approx 6\pm1$ but don't know the exact value.

Comment: Do you have a formula for the distance between a line and a parabola?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity No, I don't have it.

Comment: The intersection point on the parabola will be the exact point $(x,y)$ such that the slope of the parabola at that point is equal to the slope of the line.  In effect, on the parabola prior to this point, the parabola is *moving toward* the line, and on the parabola, after this point, the parabola is *moving away* from the line.  This idea, by itself, is enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Re previous comment, if you have a point on the parabola $(x,y)$ whose slope equals the slope of the line, then the distance from this point to the line will be the length of the line segment that is perpendicular to the line (i.e. slope is negative reciprocal), with the line segment intersecting both $(x,y)$ and *some* point on the line.

Comment: I can find two values for the slope of the line, which are however the solutions of a quartic equation. Where did you take this problem from?

Comment: I have edited your title to state what I believe you are asking. Please verify that my interpretation is correct.

Comment: @user2661923 The problem is I don't know a point on the parabola (x,y) whose slope equals the slope of the line. If I know it, I will get the answer.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca It is raised by one of the student who is in the same calculus class as me at the end of calculus class many years ago. (He isn't in the same university branch as me but we study calculus together in first year.) I can't remember who he is but I think he want to ask the different linear & parabola calculus problem to the instructor. As there is no much time left, the instructor didn't solve the problem. So, it remain unsolved for me but I don't know if he get the answer after that or not.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you. That is what I want to ask.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Does the question really have 2 answers ? How does the another answer look like ? Could you write your answer ?

Comment: @jsutforsignin The  quartic equation in the answer below is fine: you just have to solve it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point $(x_0,x_0^2)$ the parabola $y=x^2$ has tangent line $y = 2x_0(x-x_0) + x_0^2 = 2x_0x - x_0^2$.

If we slide over the line $y = ax-2a$ by the right amount, this line should become a tangent line. To find the right amount to make the normal distance equal to one, use the perpendicular slope of $-\frac{1}{a}$ and draw a right triangle with side 1, which should give you $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}}$. Then the translated line has formula $y = ax - (2a - a\sqrt{\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}})$

That means we have two equations for the same tangent line, which yields $a = 2x_0$ and $2a - a \sqrt{\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}} = x_0^2$.

That gives a quartic for $a$, and WolframAlpha gives $a = 3.8685$ or $a = 0.64851$, or the degenerate $a = -0.53086$ or $a = 12.014$, which should get you the equation for the line.

[image: a=3.8685]
[image: a=0.64851]
[image: a=-0.53086]
[image: a=12.014]

Comment: @Michael Biro I try plotting a=4.1132  in Desmos. The shortest distance looks larger than 1.

Comment: You're right, I had the reciprocal of the correct shift in my equation. Corrected now!

Comment: @jsutforsignin Here's my solution in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cypug6bgwm

Comment: Thank you. It will be great if you put the picture in your answer.